# Calling a method which gets the time in Java

Tags: java, methods, time

I am having trouble calculating time in a Java program.  When my dialog comes up, I want to get the time until a button is pressed by user.

I am thinking of making this by calling a method.  When dialog is up, I will call the method with integer number 1.  That's how I store the current time.

When the button is pressed, I call the method with integer number 2. That's why I store to another variable the current time and then return time2-time1 as the total time.

I need help on the concept of the method.

```
public long counttime(int t)
{
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    long totalTime;

    if (t==1)
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (t==2)
    {
        endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    }

    return totalTime;
}
```

This gets me error.  The 3 variables are declared, but might not be initialized.  However, I don't want these variables to be initialized, because I want the variables to be stored from another time in order to calculate the total time.

If I initialize them to 0, then every time the method runs, I lose what the variable was before and i get the default one

How do I retain the value of these variables, and make the code work as described?

Comment: Think about `t` being 3 what would `totalTime` be then? That's what the compiler is asking about.

Comment: yes i know. But wheni try to run it with integer 2, then it would take again starttime declared by new, and not by the variable which changed from the method called before.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Also, this won't work. Each method invocation will have its own start and end time, because they are local variables. To do that, the start and end time must be stored as instance fields of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to persist, then you need to store (at least the `startTime`) in a field (and handle the case when it hasn't been set). Something like,

```
private Long startTime = null;
public Long counttime(int t)
{
    if(t==1)
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(t==2 && startTime != null)
    {
        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return endTime - startTime;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This worked like it should! Thanks a lot for ur time and ur answer!